# cpp and h/hpp #include: "why" question

Tags: headers, include

Why does the source include a header and not also the other way around? I googled it but only found questions regarding the use of header files, how to include them but nowhere to say why it is like it is. 
If the header is merely the declaration, how does the compiler know the definition only from it?
For example: take `foo.cpp`, `bar.h`, `bar.cpp`. This is what everybody does:
in `foo.cpp`:
`#include "bar.h"`
but the `bar.cpp` is not included neither in the `bar.h` or `foo.cpp`. That's why I deem logical that `bar.cpp` be included in `bar.h` and so, indirectly in `foo.cpp`.

Comment: tl;dr legacy from C where it is legacy from dump compilers that could do symbolic import (as seen in every other language)

Comment: "how does the compiler know the definition only from it [the header file]" - the compiler does not, why should it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compilation of C and C++ code is done in two distinct steps.

In the first step, the source code in a single .c or .cpp file is compiled to object code. While compiling the file `foo.cpp`, the compiler needs to know that `bar` contains a method `doSomething` and what parameters that method expects and what return type it returns, but the compiler doesn't need to know exactly what the function does internally.
The compiler checks that the call in the code from `foo.cpp` matches how the function is declared (which is obtained by the #include "bar.h"), and then makes an annotation in the object code that at position X the function `bar::doSomething` is being called.

In the second step, all the source files that make up the application are linked together to create the final executable. At this point, the linker tries to replace the annotations that the compiler made in the object code with the actual address of the corresponding function. The linker is explicitly told which object files it should look at.
It is only at this point that the definitions of all functions need to be available.

Which files are needed to create an application is typically defined in a project file or a makefile.

Comment: Thank you for explanation but the question is how is `bar.cpp` made accessible? It's not `#include`-d into any of the headers or source files. How is the `bar` definition (not declaration) found?

Comment: @mireazma: While compiling `foo.cpp`, the compiler doesn't need to access `bar.cpp` at all, so there is no need to make `bar.cpp` available. At the linking stage, the linker is told to combine `foo.o` and `bar.o` into an executable. There both object files are explicitly mentioned to the linker. It is also the linker that needs to have the definitions available.

Comment: Added bonus: the *.o files can thus be compiled in parallel! (with a link step at the end)

Comment: How does the compiler know to compile `bar.cpp`? Just because it's somewhere in the project and by default all `cpp`s found are compiled or because the compiler searches for a homonym `cpp`for the corresponding `h` file `#include`d in the dependency tree?

Comment: @mireazma: The compiler knows to compiler `bar.cpp` because the IDE/make-tool tells it so, based on the fact that `bar.cpp` is listed as a source file in the project/makefile.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to know in the first place. Voted as best answer. However, I may be considered a troller but IMHO this compiler behavior is flawed since it doesn't follow a strong dependency path, it just blindly process all; you have to rely on the **convention** of `h` - `cpp` name coincidence. Not to mention if I have 2 interchangeable source files and decide to use either (not simultaneously): from my POV I'd change only an `#include` line and recompile. But from how it actually works, either the exe gets bloated or I have to keep moving files in/out of the source folder.

Comment: @mireazma: As far as C++ toolchains are concerned, there does not even have to be a correspondence between `.h` and `.cpp` files. As long as the called functions can be found somewhere, the linker is happy. This means that the functions declared in `bar.h` could be defined in `quux.cpp` or in multiple files.

Comment: @mireazma: There are also techniques that use this feature to include platform-dependent code. Then you would have the windows implementation in `bar_win.cpp` and the linux implementation in `bar_linux.cpp`. The make tool then decides, based on the platform you are building on, which of those two to compile and include in the executable.

Comment: Yes, even the correspondence you mentioned looks more appropriate but hey, who am I to argue? (0.5 sarcasm, 0.5 self-judgement)

Comment: *"but IMHO this compiler behavior is flawed since [...] it just blindly process all; you have to rely on the convention of h - cpp name coincidence"* - absolutely not, maybe you misunderstand the comments above? The compiler compiles only files **listed explicitly in a makefile** or your IDE's project file.

Comment: @doc You're right. It's not the compiler; it's MSVS fault and of the other IDE's (per Simon B -- see below) which automatically fill in the makefile/project file with all cpp's it lays its eye on. But how does the linker know where's the implementation of some function? Blind search. Lucky programmers, they have this homonymy **convention** to follow the dependency. Wouldn't it be better to specify dependencies with some directive like in `bar.h`have `#defines <bar.cpp>`? Simple, straightforward and clear.

Comment: @mireazma: nonsense. There is full control which source code files belong to a project, which one should be compiled, and which not. People here told you this more than once, but you still insist on your wrong idea of "having the compiler or IDE or linker" automatically pick those files. For example, using MSVS, look into the vcproj file of a project using a simple text editor or notepad, there is the list of cpp files which have to be compiled.

Comment: @Doc: I gladly accept somebody proving me wrong but not by flawed logic. It's not a matter of validity - never was; nor of knowledge (anymore), as I've voted for the best answer; we've been debating over a matter of concept, design. "wrong idea of "having the compiler or IDE or linker" automatically pick those files": who picked them? Not me. Then why doesn't it complain of unspecified compilation list? Because it _is_ automatic. You're implying it's at hand and obvious and everybody follows those steps you mentioned to specify the intended compilation list. I don't think it's customary.

Answer (score 5):

Your question indicates that you don't understand the compilation process (most of this will apply to c as well as c++.)

The fundamental unit of compilation is a source file; for C++ the convention is to use the .cpp file extension. The extension could be anything, but most compilers use the extension to determine how to process the file, ex. .cpp means c++, .o means object, .c means straight c, etc. Source files are **complied** into object (nominally .obj or .o) files. Object files are **linked** together to create executable files.

The compiler doesn't know anything about header files. There is a pre-processor that replaces the #include directives with the content of the header file, and processes other pre-processor directives, the resulting output is what the compiler sees as input; **this is the reason why headers are included in source files and not vice versa.**

Header files aren't strictly necessary to compile source to object; they are a tool to manage complexity, organize and modularize your source files. As the other answers have explained, when foo.cpp needs to reference something in bar.cpp, say baz(), foo.cpp needs to have some descriptive information about baz() so it can generate a reference that the linker can resolve.

One could simply put this information in foo.cpp, but this would duplicate the information in bar.cpp. The solution to this duplication is to put all the descriptive information in another file, which we call a header file (nominally .h or .hpp.) With bar.h the information that needs to be included in foo.cpp and bar.cpp is only in one file, which is inserted into the file when the pre-processor finds the #include directive. This becomes invaluable as the complexity of the project increases.

Much of the compilation process is hidden behind an IDE or a makefile. Compiling a small project by hand will be very instructive in learning how the compilation process actually works. The first time I had to write a .makefile from scratch in school all mystery about the compilation process vanished; I had to learn all the details to accomplish the task.

Compiling and linking your example would be 3 operations, in two stages:

- Compile the source files:

  - Compile foo.cpp into foo.o (ex. gcc -c -o foo.o foo.cpp)
  - Compile bar.cpp into bar.o (ex. gcc -c -o bar.o bar.cpp)
- Link the object files:

  - link foo.o and bar.o into program (ex. gcc -o program foo.o bar.o)

During the compilation stage each file is processed individually. The resulting object files contain machine code and external references (things not in the source file, but located some other source file.)

The final step is to link the objects, this is when the references are resolved, if you forget to include the object file in the link command, it will fail with unresolved external references; this is the step where all the information is needed. Modern compilers can handle all those steps with a single command, but that hides the process.

Comment: Thank you but I still need to dot the I: Does the MSVS compiler without my explicit mention, compile _all_ cpp files it finds in the project, even if not `#include`d? Or just the ones corresponding to a same named `h` file? I'd personally preferred "strong definition" as in "strong type": compile what instructed, no more no less.

Comment: The default behaviour of MSVS, and other IDEs, it to compile *all* the source files in that project.  If you tell the IDE that your project depends on another, it will go off and compile that other project first (and so on, recursively).

Comment: @mireazma putting a file into an IDE project **IS** "explicitly mentioning" it! i.e. and IDE project is equivalent to a .makefile.

Comment: @esoterik: Unfortunately true. To make things even simpler and to go with the design, header files should be also auto-included -- they're in the project, right? This would at least spare us from managing which headers to include into which headers and source files and would cut out `undefined` errors.

Comment: @mireazma newer languages like C# and Java, extract the 'header' information automatically, but they still require some sort of import directive to resolve references. The IDE can't read your mind, it won't know what headers you want to include.

Comment: @esoterik what happens if you have file1.c, which uses externally referenced bob() via file1.h and file2.c includes file1.h and defines bob() and file3.c uses externally referenced bob() via file3.h and file 4.c includes file3.h and defines bob(). If you pass all the.o files to the linker, how does the linker know which bob() it references, is there some name mangling with the header file name at compile which then appears in the unresolved symbol table? Perhaps this is an illegal scenario altogether but I can't test atm, haven't done much hands on experimentation with C

Comment: Assume file main.c includes main.h and file1.c and file2.c include main.h  and all 5 files are compiled to.o files.

Comment: @LewisKelsey this is a new question, you should post it, and/or search to see if it has been answered already elsewhere!  -- The shortest answer is: 'Namespaces'; the short answer is: this will produce a name collision, and IIRC the error message is slightly cryptic; this problem is exactly what namespaces were invented solve.  - n.b. if you have any deeper questions search/post them; don't comment on a 4 year old answer, (unless you have something new, and on topic, to add.)

Comment: @esoterik will do.

Comment: It's worth a question although I think I know the answer now. It can't be done on C as there isn't a concept of namespace so you have to rename the functions or use a work around. On C++ the namespace probably gets mangled with the function name.

Answer (score 1):

If `bar.cpp` included `bar.h` and vice versa, then there would be no point in having those two as separate files, since they would be effectively identical.

But there *is* a point: you *don't need* the definition for most tasks. Compiling a module that uses the services of `bar` only needs to know that `bar` contains a method `doThings()` which takes an `int` and returns an `int`. It does *not* need to know how `bar` achieves this (indeed, that is the entire point of modules). Therefore, when compiling another module, the compiler only bothers to read the header file, but when compiling `bar` itself it reads both files. In a large system composed of many modules, this saves a huge amount of effort because every line of *definition* code is compiled only once and not many times.

Comment: Thanks. So should I take it the compiler automatically reads cpp files based on their corresponding h names, and only if these h files are included somewhere in the execution "tree"? This is what I understand.

Comment: Typically a compiler reads a `.cpp` file *only* if you explicitly tell it to, e.g. via `gcc -o bar.o bar.cpp`. It's the `.h` files that are read implicitly, because they're named in `#include` directives.

Comment: But this is precisely the question: how does the compiler/linker know of the unincluded cpp's, the ones corresponding to headers? How do they know where to look for the definitions of declared variables/functions in the headers?

Comment: @mireazma:  It doesn't.  You have to tell the compiler to compile the sources you want compiled and those sources have to include the headers for things they need.  Similarly, the linker has to be told to link the objects and libraries the program needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a compiler, then Life is easy so long as you know what everything "looks like".  For example, 'X' is a 64-bit integer, 'Y' is a pointer to something of that Type, 'Z' is an array of this Type and size, and so on. 
Take this to the extreme and you get an early Pascal compiler, where the **main** method has to be the very *last* thing in the source file!  Everything else has to be defined first.  Writing code in this way is painful, because the order is natural to the *compiler* but not to the likes of you and me.

Enter the Header (.h) file.

It describes all the methods that that appear in your .cpp file so the compiler can "make a note" of what they look like (known as "forward declarations") and then just recognise them when they appear, again, further down in the code.  Otherwise, it just has to assume some "default" definition for any method and then complain like mad when it finds a different implmentation signature (some Solaris compilers assume "int methodName( int )" as a default, IIRC.

But, even with all this, you still don't *need* a Header file.

You can do all that within the .cpp file itself.

Now add "reusable code" into the mix.  *Other* .cpp files want to use the methods in *your* .cpp file but the compiler still needs to know what those methods "look like".

By splitting the method declarations out into a Header file, you're effectively "publishing" the API provided by your .cpp file.  (ADA has "package" and "package body", most of the Microsoft world just smooshes all the declaration and implementation details into a single file, the dll).

So the Header file gives you a single declaration of your methods, usable by both you and any number of others who might need to use those methods.  Note, however, that the people using your *Header* file don't need your .cpp file at all; [object] code compiled in this way always has "holes" in it (unresolved function pointers); it's the *linker's* job to join all the dots together.

Comment: Yes, I know the use and usefulness of headers. Yet thank you for the informative answer.